# Hide cmd window in Windows Forms Application

Tags: winforms, cmd, hide

I have to use cmd command in WFA, for example:

```
system(erase /q);
```

So, now i have two windows - cmd and my app.
It's working but I would like hide cmd window.

Any ideas?

---

Oh, I forgot add name of language, sorry for that, it's C++. Your code seems nice, I try "change" it for C++:

```
System::Diagnostics::Process process = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process();
System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo ^ startInfo = gcnew
System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo->WindowStyle = System::Diagnostics::ProcessWindowStyle::Hidden;
startInfo->FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo->Arguments = "system(linkStr)";
process->StartInfo = startInfo;
process->Start();
```

but it return error:

> 'System::Diagnostics::Process' : class does not have a
>   copy-constructor

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `System::Diagnostics::Process ^process = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process();`?

Comment: gcnew returns a handle, identified by the ^ symbol. Change the code as Thomas suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to hide the cmd window in c#.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "system(erase /q)";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
```